# Draw precise circle through two points

Tags: python, graphics, drawing, python-imaging-library

I am programming an application for high precision measurements. Now I have a problem.

User can select a segment on axis X that would represent diameter of a circle.
How do I draw the circle in question through two selected end points if the selected diameter has even pixel length
In this case origin of the circle would be between two pixels, which would make me choose one of them, thus shifting the circle one pixel left or right.
It is true, the look wouldn't change because one pixel will be included and another added on the other side of selected segment, but what if I need to draw a square based on the segment's length around the area first.
Then circle and square would touch in wrong places.

What is usually done in this circumstances?

Comment: What is usually done is to allow the center of the circle to be on half-pixel boundaries.

Comment: And how exactly is this done. I mean, drawing correct circle I can imagine (using polar to cartesian with trigonometry or circle equation), but still where you put the origin if you have to draw it? Do you use both pixels or simply ignore the fact that it isn't mathematically correct? I mean, you cannot draw between two pixels. :D

Answer (score 0):

[`ImageDraw.Draw.ellipse`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.ellipse) takes a bounding box as a parameter. It doesn't care where the center of the circle goes.

The circle outline includes all 4 edges of the bounding box in the tests I performed. I suggest you do your own tests too.

Calculating the bounding box from two arbitrary points is easy, once you have the diameter and center of the circle.

```
diameter = ((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2) ** 0.5
radius = diameter / 2
xC, yC = (x1 + x2) / 2.0, (y1 + y2) / 2.0
bbox = [round(xC - radius), round(yC - radius), round(xC + radius), round(yC + radius)]
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but I still care what will happen when I use it. Would the real ellipse be drawn instead of a circle to touch all sides of a bounding box square with even length of its side D. Or would it draw a real circle but use R = int(D/2.0) and leave one pixel right and one down circle free?